# ZeroMQ build issue in julia

Tags: julia, zeromq, failed-installation, ijulia-notebook

When trying to install IJulia ( for Julia v0.6 ), I ran into a problem with installing/building ZeroMQ.

So I tried ( as suggested by someone ) to rebuild ZeroMQ after restarting Julia. I tried this several times, both at home and at work ( maybe proxy problems were at play ), but I still got the following error:

> julia> Pkg.build("ZMQ") INFO: Building WinRPM WARNING: Compat.KERNEL
>   is deprecated.   likely near
>   C:\Users\ksmet1977.julia\v0.6\WinRPM\src\WinRPM.jl:4 INFO:
>   Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>   INFO: Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>   INFO: Building ZMQ WARNING: Compat.KERNEL is deprecated.   likely near
>   C:\Users\kevin.smet.julia\v0.6\WinRPM\src\WinRPM.jl:4 INFO: Updating
>   WinRPM package list INFO: Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>   INFO: Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>
> =====================================================[ ERROR: ZMQ ]====
>
> LoadError: None of the selected providers can install dependency zmq.
>   Use BinDeps.debug(package_name) to see available providers while
>   loading C:\Users\kevin.smet.julia\v0.6\ZMQ\deps\build.jl, in
>   expression starting on line 35
>
> ====================================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]====
>   =========================================== WARNING: ZMQ had
>   build errors.
>    - packages with build errors remain installed in C:\Users\kevin.smet.julia\v0.6
>    - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("ZMQ")`
>    - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

Note that I had already fixed the `WinRPM` problem with downloading when installing some other package by deleting the `cache.julialang.org` part in the **`sources.list`** file.

When I run **`BinDeps.debug("ZMQ")`**, I get the following message:

> INFO: Reading build script... WARNING: Compat.KERNEL is deprecated.
>   likely near C:\Users\kevin.smet.julia\v0.6\WinRPM\src\WinRPM.jl:4 The
>   package declares 1 dependencies. INFO: Updating WinRPM package list
>   INFO: Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>   INFO: Downloading
>   http:/download.opensuse.org/repositories/windows:/mingw:/win32/openSUSE_Leap_42.2/repodata/repomd.xml
>
> - Library "zmq"
>
>   - Providers:
>
>     - Autotools Build
>     - BinDeps.AptGet package libzmq3 (can't provide)
>     - BinDeps.Yum package czmq (can't provide)
>     - WinRPM.RPM package zeromq (can't provide)

I'm on windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found.
When updating the sources list in WinRPM I used twice "win32". After changing one of the sources to win64 the problem was solved.